# how to print the progress of the files being copied in bash

Tags: perl, bash

I have a perl script in which I am copying a file from a network mounted path to a local path using the basic bash "cp" command. But the file copying is taking a lot of time.

Can you please help me how to notify the user using the script - the progress while copying like say so much of kbytes of file have been copied or a percentage of file copied...

Can you help me in the perl code for the above task.

Comment: That's a shame, I have the exact script you needed.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jcreasey/7935778dffc18ee8d523